# Why does my simulation of nearest neighbors as circle origins provide different non-contact probability compared to theoretical?

Tags: simulation, stochastic-processes, poisson-process, geometry

I am simulating spatially distributed points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with intensity $\lambda$ (units 1/area), which act as circle origins with radii being a random variable $R_k$. Given the distance to the $k$th nearest neighbor $D_k$ (see e.g. [Moltchanov 2012](http://www.cs.tut.fi/%7Emoltchan/pubs/distances2011.pdf)), the contact probability of the circle located in the origin (denoted with subscript 0) with the circle originated as the $k$th neighbor is
\begin{equation}
P(\mathrm{contact \ with \ circle\ } k) = P(R_0 + R_k \ge D_k).
\end{equation}
As a MWE, I will use $R_k \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and Poisson process for spatial. The distance distribution then follows a generalized Gamma distribution
\begin{equation}
f_{D_k}(r) = \frac{2(\lambda \pi r^2)^k}{r \Gamma(k)}e^{-\lambda \pi r^2}, \quad r > 0, \ k=1,2,\dots
\end{equation}
The sum distribution of two identical normally distributed radii is
\begin{equation}
R_0 + R_k \equiv Z \sim \mathcal{N}(2 \mu, 2 \sigma^2)
\end{equation}
The contact probability is then calculated from
\begin{equation}
P(\mathrm{contact \ with \ circle\ } k) = \int_{0^+}^\infty f_Z(r) F_{D_k}(r) dr
\end{equation}
The probability of the circle in the origin *not* being in contact with any of the $M$ nearest neighbors is then
\begin{equation}
P(\mathrm{not \ in \ contact \ with \ any}) = \prod_{k=1}^{M}(1-P(\mathrm{contact \ with \ circle\ } k))
\end{equation}
**The probability of non-contact I get differs from the simulation by quite a big margin (up to >20 times difference), and I fail to understand why?**

### List of checks performed

- The distance distributions agree with the simulated
- The distribution of the sum of two radii is correct
- In the simulation, I try to eliminate the boundary effects by only considering the circles with origins within some distance from the simulation borders
- Simulation is performed with relatively high $\lambda$, large $A$ and multiple repeats to ensure the variability is not the root cause for the difference

### MWE python code and sample outputs

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import poisson, norm, gengamma
from scipy.integrate import trapz
%matplotlib inline

plt.rcParams["font.size"] = 12
np.random.seed(1)
# Circle size parameters
mu = 0.02
sigma = 0.2*mu
# Circle density [1/area]
la = 600.0
A = 20.0 # Area
w = np.sqrt(A) # Width
##############
# Simulation #
##############
N = poisson.rvs(la*A) # Number of circles
xs = np.random.rand(N)*w # Simulated x-coordinates
ys = np.random.rand(N)*w # Simulated y-coordinates
# Border effect - consider only circles that are some distance away from the simulation border
val_ind = (xs >= 0.1*w) & (xs <= 0.9*w) & (ys >= 0.1*w) & (ys <= 0.9*w)
print("N = %i, N_val = %i"%(N, sum(val_ind)))
rs = np.random.randn(N)*sigma + mu # Simulated radii

Ds = np.zeros((N,N)) # Distance matrix
contact = np.zeros((N,N), dtype=bool) # Contact-indicator matrix
for i in range(N):
    Ds[i,:] = np.sqrt((xs[i] - xs)**2 + (ys[i] - ys)**2) # Distances to other circle centers
    contact[i,rs[i] + rs >= Ds[i,:]] = True # Determine which circles are in contact

np.fill_diagonal(contact, False) # Remove self-contact
Ds_sorted = np.sort(Ds) # Sort by distance
contact_counts = np.sum(contact, axis=0)
print("P(no contact) = %.2f%%"%(float(sum(contact_counts[val_ind]==0))/sum(val_ind)*100))

########################
# Prediction and plots #
########################
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12.,5.))
rv_z = norm(2.0*mu, np.sqrt(2.0)*sigma) # Sum of two normally distributed radii, both with parameters (mu, sigma)
# Number of nearest neighbors to be considered
M_candidates = np.arange(1,101)
M = M_candidates[np.where(gengamma.ppf(1e-4, M_candidates, 2, scale=(la*np.pi)**(-1.0/2.0)) > rv_z.ppf(1.0 - 1e-4))[0][0]]
r = np.linspace(0.0, gengamma.ppf(1.0-1e-4, M, 2, scale=(la*np.pi)**(-1.0/2.0)), 400) # Distance / radius
# Z = R_i + R_j

fz = rv_z.pdf(r)
Fz = rv_z.cdf(r)
line, = plt.plot(r, fz, 'k-', linewidth=2)
rs2 = rs.copy()
np.random.shuffle(rs2)
zs = rs + rs2 # Simulate sum of two radii
plt.hist(zs, bins=50, density=True, color=line.get_color(), alpha=0.3)

ps = np.zeros(M) # Probabilities of being in contact with ith nearest circle
for i in range(1, M+1):
    fd = gengamma.pdf(r, i, 2, scale=(la*np.pi)**(-1.0/2.0)) # Distance to ith neighbour pdf
    Fd = gengamma.cdf(r, i, 2, scale=(la*np.pi)**(-1.0/2.0)) # Distance to ith neighbour cdf
    line, = plt.plot(r, fd)
    plt.text(r[np.argmax(fd)], 1.05*np.max(fd), str(i))
    plt.hist(Ds_sorted[:,i], bins=50, density=True, alpha=0.3, color=line.get_color()) # Simulated distances to ith
    ps[i-1] = trapz(Fd*fz, r) # P(contact) = P(R_0 + R_i \ge D_i)
    print("i = %i, P(contact with circle %i) = %f%%"%(i, i, ps[i-1]*100))

plt.xlim([0.0, r.max()])
plt.xlabel("$r,d$")
plt.ylabel("$f(r), f(d)$")
print("P(no contact to any of the circles) = %.2f%%"%((np.prod(1.0-ps))*100))
```

with output prints

```
N = 11974, N_val = 7715
P(no contact) = 6.21%
i = 1, P(contact with circle 1) = 93.595769%
i = 2, P(contact with circle 2) = 77.871000%
i = 3, P(contact with circle 3) = 56.891694%
i = 4, P(contact with circle 4) = 36.800897%
i = 5, P(contact with circle 5) = 21.376076%
i = 6, P(contact with circle 6) = 11.307534%
i = 7, P(contact with circle 7) = 5.514789%
i = 8, P(contact with circle 8) = 2.505546%
i = 9, P(contact with circle 9) = 1.069581%
i = 10, P(contact with circle 10) = 0.432070%
i = 11, P(contact with circle 11) = 0.166151%
i = 12, P(contact with circle 12) = 0.061127%
i = 13, P(contact with circle 13) = 0.021606%
i = 14, P(contact with circle 14) = 0.007364%
i = 15, P(contact with circle 15) = 0.002428%
i = 16, P(contact with circle 16) = 0.000776%
i = 17, P(contact with circle 17) = 0.000241%
i = 18, P(contact with circle 18) = 0.000073%
i = 19, P(contact with circle 19) = 0.000022%
i = 20, P(contact with circle 20) = 0.000006%
P(no contact to any of the circles) = 0.24%
```

And output plot with the distribution of two radii added together as black thicker line and the distances to $k$th neighbor, both predicted (continuous lines) and simulated (histograms):
[image: Predicted and simulated distances]

So the predicted non-contact probability is 0.24% whereas the simulated is 6.21%. So there is obviously something wrong with my analysis/simulation. The distributions shown in the plot above indicate that the predicted non-contact probability is plausible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a circular inspection area described by a radius $R$ filled with points from Poisson process, the cumulative density function for distances to the origin is
\begin{equation}
F_{ro}(r) = \frac{r^2}{R^2}
\end{equation}
The number of points follows Poisson distribution $N \sim \mathrm{Poi}(\lambda \pi R^2)$ points that act as circle origins with radius pdf $f_r(r)$, we calculate the probability that all $N$ points are further away from the origin than $r_0 + r_j$:
\begin{equation}
\int \int \dots \int \left(1 - \left(\frac{r_0 + r_1}{R}\right)^2 \right) f_{r}(r_1) \left(1 - \left(\frac{r_0 + r_2}{R}\right)^2 \right) f_{r}(r_2)\dots \left(1 - \left(\frac{r_0 + r_n}{R}\right)^2 \right) f_{r}(r_n) f_r(r_0) dr_0dr_1dr_2 \dots dr_n
\end{equation}
In the integrand, we see the term repeating
\begin{equation}
g(r_0) = \int_0^{R - r_0} \left(1 - \left(\frac{r_0 + r_j}{R}\right)^2 \right) f_{r}(r_j) dr_j
\end{equation}
Expanding the terms, we get
\begin{equation}
g(r_0) = \int_0^{R-r_0} \left(1 - \frac{r_0^2}{R^2} \right) f_{r}(r_j) dr_j - \int_0^{R-r_0} \frac{2r_0 r_j}{R^2} f_{r}(r_j) dr_j - \int_0^{R-r_0} \frac{r_j^2}{R^2} f_{r}(r_j) dr_j
\end{equation}
Assuming $R \gg r_j$ so the whole support of $f_r$ is covered by the integrals, we can use the moments. For Normally distributed radius, used in the MWE:
\begin{equation}
g(r_0) = 1  - \frac{r_0^2}{R^2} - 2\frac{r_0 \mu}{R^2} - \frac{\mu^2 + \sigma^2}{R^2}
\end{equation}
This term is then in power $N$ in the integrand. Marginalizing over $N$ with Poisson gives
\begin{equation}
\sum_{N=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \lambda \pi R^2 \right)^N}{N!}e^{-\lambda \pi R^2} g(r_0)^N = e^{-\lambda \pi  \left(\mu^{2} + 2 \mu r_{0} + r_{0}^{2} + \sigma^{2}\right)}
\end{equation}
And the integrand reduces to
\begin{equation}
P(\mathrm{no \ contact}) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda \pi \left( (r_0 + \mu)^2 + \sigma^2 \right)} f_r(r_0) d r_0,
\end{equation}
which resembles the void probability.

Generalizing to the situation of analyzing $k$ in contact we have
\begin{equation}
P(\mathrm{ k \ in \ contact}) = {N \choose k} \int (1-g(r_0))^k g(r_0)^{N - k} f_r(r_0) d r_0
\end{equation}
Using Poisson process marginalisation, we get
\begin{equation}
\sum_{N=k}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \lambda \pi R^2 \right)^N}{N!}e^{-\lambda \pi R^2} {N \choose k} \left(1 - g(r_0)\right)^k  g(r_0)^{N-k} = \frac{1}{k!} \left(\lambda \pi  \left(\mu^{2} + 2 \mu r_{0} + r_{0}^{2} + \sigma^{2}\right)\right)^{k} e^{- \lambda \pi  \left(\mu^{2} + 2 \mu r_{0} + r_{0}^{2} + \sigma^{2}\right)}
\end{equation}
And the integrand reduces to
\begin{equation}
P(\mathrm{k \ in \ contact}) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \left(\lambda \pi  \left(\mu^{2} + 2 \mu r_{0} + r_{0}^{2} + \sigma^{2}\right)\right)^{k} e^{- \lambda \pi  \left(\mu^{2} + 2 \mu r_{0} + r_{0}^{2} + \sigma^{2}\right)} f_r(r_0) d r_0
\end{equation}

```
integrand = np.exp(-la*np.pi*((r + mu)**2 + sigma**2))*norm.pdf(r, mu, sigma)
np.trapz(integrand, r)*100
5.4814107319269727
```

The original simulation repeated 1000 times gave the following mean and standard deviation

```
5.4778231056151725, 0.32231380209045535
```

And testing the $k$ in contact against the latest simulation shows that the method works:

```
for k in range(10):
    integrand = (la*np.pi*((r + mu)**2 + sigma**2))**k/np.math.factorial(k)*np.exp(-la*np.pi*((r + mu)**2 + sigma**2))*norm.pdf(r, mu, sigma)
    Pk = trapz(integrand, r)
    print("P(%i simulation) = %f%%, P(%i prediction) = %f%%"%(k, float(sum(contact_counts[val_ind]==k))/sum(val_ind)*100, k, Pk*100))

P(0 simulation) = 5.405055%, P(0 prediction) = 5.481411%
P(1 simulation) = 15.307842%, P(1 prediction) = 15.025431%
P(2 simulation) = 21.762800%, P(2 prediction) = 21.434454%
P(3 simulation) = 21.646144%, P(3 prediction) = 21.169541%
P(4 simulation) = 16.642903%, P(4 prediction) = 16.252296%
P(5 simulation) = 9.163966%, P(5 prediction) = 10.327228%
P(6 simulation) = 5.703176%, P(6 prediction) = 5.648840%
P(7 simulation) = 2.475697%, P(7 prediction) = 2.731836%
P(8 simulation) = 1.335062%, P(8 prediction) = 1.190860%
P(9 simulation) = 0.298121%, P(9 prediction) = 0.474791%
```

Why the nearest neighbor distances cannot be used remains unclear to me. The results *should* generalize to other radius distributions $f_r$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
P(\mathrm{k \ in \ contact}) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \left(\pi \lambda \left(r_{0}^{2} + 2 r_{0} \int r f_r(r) dr  + \int r^2 f_r(r) dr\right)\right)^{k} e^{- \pi \lambda \left(r_{0}^{2} + 2 r_{0} \int r f_r(r) dr +  \int r^2 f_r(r) dr\right)} f_r(r_0) d r_0
\end{equation}